# Why do I get list index out of range in my twitter weather bot application

Tags: python, api, bots, weather

I have created a bot that interacts with users tweets and reply with the weather of the location the user tweets with in the # e.g. "Whats the weather like in #London". The bot will then reply with what the weather is currently in London.

When i run the bot, it runs fine and finds the URL to get the data of the weather and stores the tweet, but when it needs to reply with the weather, i get a list index out of range.

the code:

```
def get_location(tweet):
    #takes tweet and returns only the substring attached to hashtag
    tweet_location = [i.strip("#") for i in tweet.split() if i.startswith("#")][0]
    tweet_location += " today weather.com"
    return tweet_location

def get_weather(query):
    for url in search(query, stop=1):
        print("Results is " + url)

    #this code sends a request and reads the webpage enclsed to the request
    request = Request(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})

    webpage = urlopen(request).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")

    try:
        title = soup.findAll("span", "today-daypart-title")[0].string 
        phrase = soup.findAll("span", "today-daypart-wxphrase")[0].string
    except IndexError as e:
        forecast = (" could not find the weather, check back later")
        print(e)
    else:
        forecast = (" forecast for " + title + " is " + phrase)
        print(forecast)

    return forecast


def reply_to_tweet():
    print("retrieving and replying to tweets...")
    last_seen_tweet = read_last_seen(FILE_NAME)
    # mentions_timeline() returns a list of 20 most recent mentions
    mentions = api.mentions_timeline(last_seen_tweet, tweet_mode="extended")

    # reversing to read old tweets first
    for mention in reversed(mentions):
        print(str(mention.id) + " - " + mention.full_text)
        last_seen_tweet = mention.id
        store_last_seen(FILE_NAME, last_seen_tweet)
        if "#" in mention.full_text.lower():
            print("found #")

            location = get_location(mention.full_text)
            weather = get_weather(location)

            # responding to tweet mention
            api.update_status("@" + mention.user.screen_name + weather, mention.id)
```

The output from running the code:

```
retrieving and replying to tweets...
1386417114316169219 - @UniProjectbot #Birmingham
found #
Results is https://weather.com/en-GB/weather/today/l/Birmingham+England?canonicalCityId=de781cf30dc9d9dbea1ed33096e3729fe38d4023bb06259589d311d034072b9d
list index out of range
```

Comment: If you are asking *why* you are getting an indexerror, its because `soup.findAll("span", "today-daypart-wxphrase")` or `soup.findAll("span", "today-daypart-wxphrase")` return empty lists. If you are asking *why either of the above return empty lists*, you need to look at the docs.

Comment: I'm using this to find the weather information on a given location, the location is found though hashtags. I cannot find any reason why they return empty, the url that is given through the code is correct and works.